# pre-roll for youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'd like to play two different youtube videos in the same player, first video being played BEFORE the second (serving as a pre-roll ad). Sort of custom playlist consisting of only two videos.

What i really need is that when the player is in idle state it has to show the image of the main video (the second one), not the pre-roll.

So, I thought I have to use the youtube api to load the main video, then to stop it, then to load the pre-roll and after playing the pre-roll to play the main video then stop.

I've tried to copy/paste same code for achieving these tasks but i'm stuck in it. Can anybody give me an working example for this? Or, at least some advice? Many thanks.

Comment: thank you Paul for your suggestion but it is not what i need. I need to play a video BEFORE the second one, just like in a playlist.

Comment: just thought you might be able to grab some of the code from the page perhaps :)

Comment: of course i had a look but there was nothing for me there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little crude, but accomplishes your task by listening for the state change events; you could make it more responsive by integrating some smart lookahead monitoring based on cueing the main video as the preroll is getting close to finishing. But anyway, this should at least get you started:

```
    <div id="player"></div>
      <script>
      var seenPreroll=false;
      var preroll='rl1qKqlYy8M';
      var mainfeature='u1zgFlCw8Aw';
      var playingId='';
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: mainfeature,
          events: {
            'onStateChange': function(event) {
                        if (event.data==1&&seenPreroll==false) {
                                player.pauseVideo();
                                player.loadVideoById(preroll);
                                playingId=preroll;
                                seenPreroll=true;
                                player.playVideo();
                        }
                        else if (event.data==0&&playingId==preroll) {
                                player.loadVideoById(mainfeature);
                                playingId=mainfeature;
                                player.playVideo();
                        }
                }
          }
        });

}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much Jarom for writing this script, you made my day. It works exactly how a pre-roll is supposed to work. :)

Comment: Glad it helped ... if you get a chance to mark the answer as accepted, it'll help others find it, too!

Comment: I thought i did it already, I'm pretty new here, on 'stackoverflow'. I'll check again. BTW, you can see a working example of your script here: http://psihoterapie.net/video :)

Comment: How can I use this on a blog? Using it in multiple posts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456290/pre-roll-youtube-video-for-many-articles-in-a-blog